# Verification of proof of convergence in $p$-adic fields

Tags: limits, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, p-adic-number-theory

I've been studying $p$-adic fields and convergence of series in them and I've been working on a proof that $
lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} |n!|_{p} = 0$ in any $p$-adic field. I came up with the following proof and I was just wondering if it was correct.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $n! \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $n! = p^{t}r$, where $r > 0$ and $(p,r)=1$. Let $n > \frac{r}{\epsilon}$. Then,

\begin{equation*}
n! = p^{t}r>n>\frac{r}{\epsilon}\implies p^{t} > \frac{1}{\epsilon} \implies p^{-t} < \epsilon.
\end{equation*}

Since $|n!|_{p} = |p^{t}r|_{p}=p^{-t}$, we have $|n!|_{p} = p^{-t} < \epsilon$, completing the proof.

I was also trying to show the same limit is true for $n^{2}$ and it seems to me that I could use the exact same method, since $n^{2} = p^{t}r$ is also true. Does this mean that increasing sequences of natural numbers always converge in the $p$-adic fields, since each of them can be expressed in this way?

Comment: Try to find a strictly increasing sequence with two distinct cluster points that it alternates between term by term. Consider the trivial cases.

Comment: @CyclotomicField If we're alternating between two cluster points, isn't it true that one of those has to be bigger than the other and so then the series wouldn't be strictly increasing?

Comment: What happens when $t=0$?

Comment: Your proof is wrong because you do not take into account that $t$ depends on $n$. (Otherwise you would show that an arbitrary sequence of natural numbers converges $p$-adically for all $p$, which is clearly nonsense.) You'll have to use more about the factorial to prove the first assertion. -- The sequence $n^2$ does not converge $p$-adically for any $p$, e.g. note that $\lvert n^2 \rvert_p =1$ for all $n$ not divisible by $p$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Ok, I see what you're saying

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I get what you're saying -- I had kind of thought that there was something wrong because the assertion didn't really make sense, as you pointed out. I'm not seeing how to proceed with the original proof; I think I might have showed that $p^{\frac{t(t+1)}{2}} \mid n!$, but then I still don't know where to go from there.

Comment: One way, since numbers divisible by $p$ occur every $p$, $|n!|_p \le p^{-\lfloor \frac n p\rfloor} \le p (p^{-\frac 1 p})^n \to 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For which $n$ is $n!$ divisible by $p$? For all (!) $n \ge ...$

For which $n$ is $n!$ divisible by $p^2$? For all (!) $n \ge ...$

(If you don't see it immediately, just literally write $n!$ down up to, say, $n=15$, and check divisibility for $p=2$, then for $p=3, p=5, p=7$.)

What about $p^3, p^4, ..., p^k$?

(And notice that e.g. for the sequence $a_n := n^2$, there is no $N$ such that $p$ divides *all* $a_n$ for $n \ge N$; there's always some which are not divisible by $p$, let alone higher powers of $p$.)

Comment: So; Let $\epsilon > 0$. By the Archimedean Property, there exists $p^{-k} < \epsilon$. For all $n > p^{k}$, we have $n! = p^{k}t$ for some $t \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, $|n!|_{p} = |p^{k}t|_{p} = |p^{k}|_{p}|t|_{p} = p^{-k}|t|_{p} < p^{-k} < \epsilon$. Does that work?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I was just looking over this question and I was wondering if my answer was indeed correct; isn't the field $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ non-Archimedean? So then we couldn't use the Archimedean Property as I first asserted.

Comment: You're just using the archimedean property of $\mathbb R$ to find a $p^{-k}$ which is smaller than a given $\epsilon \in \mathbb R$. On that side of the inequality, you are in good old real numbers and all is fine.

Comment: I see, thank you!